# Is it true that once property is used in Python, it'd always be better initializing via property?

Tags: python, class, oop, properties, private-members

I used to initialize private attributes in `__init__` like below (this way of initializing is also commonly seen),

```
class Duck():
    def __init__(self, input_name): 
        self.__name = input_name

        @property 
        def name(self): 
            return self.__name 

        @name.setter 
        def name(self, input_name): 
            self.__name = input_name

        # Use private attribute __name internally for other purposes below...
```

---

But I just want to make sure if it is actually safer to just use property at the very beginning `__init__`, for example, in next example, for input greater than 1000 or less than 0, I want to evaluate to 1000 and 0, respectively, rather than the original input value. It seems I can't use `self.__x = x`,

```
class P:
    def __init__(self,x):
        # If self.__x = x, not desirable
        self.x = x 

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.__x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        if x < 0:
            self.__x = 0
        elif x > 1000:
            self.__x = 1000
        else:
            self.__x = x
```

Comment: 1. Don't use double leading underscores, it invokes name mangling. 2. Don't introduce the property until you actually need it. 3. Yes, it makes sense to use the setter in `__init__` too, as long as you've followed 2.

Comment: If you want to invoke the property's setter, you'll have to go through the property.

Comment: @jonrsharpe the name mangling can be a good thing, especially for safety in inheritance. It's not cut and dry that double underscores shouldn't be used. I think you need to explain 2 more clearly.

Comment: @jonrsharpe For name mangling, what if a variable should just only be used internally by developers? Shouldn't I consider using private variables?

Comment: A single leading underscore `self._name` indicates private by convention, save name mangling for when you actually need to avoid collisions. In neither case is the attribute actually inaccessible. As for not introducing properties too early, your first snippet which introduces indirection without any actual functionality is a good example of a pointless use of a property, just access `name`.

Comment: A single leading underscore indicates private, not protected? @jonrsharpe

Comment: What do you think the difference is? Python doesn't have the same encapsulation concepts as e.g. Java and C#. *"We're all consenting adults here."*

Answer (score -2):

I assume you work with python2. Properties are not supported for old-style classes. Just change the first line to

```
class P(object):
```

And whether you use `self._x` or `self.__x` for the attribute behind does not matter. Just do it consistent, i.e. change the constructor line back to

```
self.__x = x
```

Just don't call that `self.x` as the property.

**Edit:**
There was a misunderstanding I think. Here the complete code I propose:

```
class P(object):
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.__x = x

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.__x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        if x < 0:
            self.__x = 0
        elif x > 1000:
            self.__x = 1000
        else:
            self.__x = x

p = P(3)
p.x = 1001
print p.x
```

**Edit 2 - The actual question:**
I apologize, did simply not grasp the heading and actual question here, but was focused on making your class work. My distraction was that if you are in python2 and use old-style classes, the setter would not really get called.

Then like indicated in the comment-conversation below, I don't have a definite answer on **whether to initialize the attribute or the property**, but I (personally) would say:

a. If the initialisation deserves the same validation as performed in
    the setter, then use the property, as else you'd need to copy the
    setter code.

b. If however the value to initialise doesn't need validation (for
    instance, you set it to an a priori validated constant default
    value), then there is no reason to use the property.

Comment: Sorry if I offended someone - the downvote. If it does not work, sorry, I would be willing to fix it. If it is about the underscores: Yes, underscores matter, but not to solve this issue.

Comment: Considering that the questioner states an explicit desire for the behavior of the property's setter, why do you advise bypassing it?

Comment: I see now that my "Just don't call the `self.x` as the property was not a happy formulation. Please see the complete code I now posted. What I wanted to say is: Avoid name clash between the internal attribute and the property.

Comment: But you haven't addressed the OP's actual question, which was about whether you should invoke the setter from `__init__` or set the backing attribute directly.

Comment: Good point, I must admit that I didn't. Technically, both is possible, and I didn't find either official recommended. My personal opinion: If the constructor argument deserves the same validation as the setter, it would be foolish to copy/paste the code, so yes, use the property.

Comment: Let me add that I was just focused on the statement "_It seems I can't use self.__x = x_" - and guilty in "Read the f* heading even if it is 10:00 pm." Apologies!